# Windows all disapeared but are still running

Tags: xubuntu, unicode

I am running Xubuntu, and I was playing around with unicode characters, when I noticed that all of my open windows and applications, except the text editor I was working with.

Somehow they're still all running. I was listening to internet radio, and Its still playing.

Is there a way to get my windows all back? Do I need to kill them all and re-open them? Or is there another solution entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu but maybe you switched workspaces? I don't know how to switch back unless you have the switch workspace button on the taskbar though... Good luck!

Comment: I didnt even know I had multiple workspaces.
its like a second monitor that I cant see!

Thanks

Comment: I've been teaching ubuntu for years and as many of my students ran into this problem, I'm not the least bit surprised they removed the default FOUR desktops in versions higher than 12.04, though it is still an option to add them.